# How to Woocommerce display total products in stock in a single category at client´s frontend?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

hope you´re doing great.
Here is the thing...since I have assignated categories to certain customers I´m working on a shortcode to display total products quantity in category for instance "Furnitures", here´s what I´ve done so far but not properly working...any hint?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    $term = get_term_by('slug', 'furniture', 'product_cat');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term->term_id,
                'include_children' => true
            )
        )
    );
    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $count = 0;
    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
            if ($product->get_stock_quantity() > 0) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    echo 'Products in stock: ' . $count;
}

?>
```

Display quantity count of in stock products in a specific Woocommerce category

Comment: Please explain "but not properly working"

Comment: Hi mujuonly, thanks for your reply.
meaning doesn´t work at all...